# The property org.appformer.m2repo.url is not correctly set

Tags: jbpm, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

When I am trying to create a project under space with jbpm 7.31, I am getting the error below .

> 15:49:13,079 WARN 
>   [org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2RepoServiceImpl] (default task-4)
>   The url null is not valid. Using the default. 15:49:13,079 ERROR
>   [org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2RepoServiceImpl] (default task-4)
>   The property org.appformer.m2repo.url is not correctly set. The
>   workbench will use a direct file path to the m2 repository and this
>   should only be used when test the workbench. 15:49:13,079 WARN 
>   [org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2RepoServiceImpl] (default task-4)
>   The url null is not valid. Using the default.